# Запись видео и обработка

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно записать видео и отредактировать(добавить текст на видео или фильтры какие нибудь) как в Instagram.

Погуглив по запросу "*Запись видео*" получил несколько вариантов. Одни пишут `MediaRecorder` использовать, другие что лучше `MediaMuxer` чем `MediaRecorder`. Но `MediaMuxer` оказывается поддерживается Android 4.3 и выше, а мне нужно чтобы 4.1 и выше.

Почитал еще о `Ffmpeg` которую я совсем не понял. Пишут что нужно написать команды, но так и не понял куда писать. Да и с чем он работает, `SurfaceView` или `TextureView`. День просидел а результата ноль.

Вопрос: Подскажите, что с чем едят? Буду благодарен если прикрепите ссылочку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С `MediaRecorder` и прочими относительно низкоуровневыми компонентами будет много бойлерплейт-кода, поэтому, для записи видео советую использовать сторонние библиотеки.

Например, при помощи [CameraKit](https://github.com/wonderkiln/CameraKit-Android) процесс записи сведется к:

```
camera.setCameraListener(new CameraListener() {
    @Override
    public void onVideoTaken(File video) {
        super.onVideoTaken(video);
        // The File parameter is an MP4 file.
    }
});

camera.startRecordingVideo();
camera.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        camera.stopRecordingVideo();
    }
}, 2500);
```

Отдельно стоит написать про проигрывание видео. Стандартные компоненты вроде `VideoView` в некоторых ситуациях (на некоторых устройствах) могут повести себя очень непредсказуемо, поэтому, для проигрывания видео советую использовать [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer).

По поводу ffmpeg: его нужно либо собирать из исходников, либо можно использовать [вот эту](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) удобную обертку.

> Пишут что нужно написать команды, но так и не понял куда писать

Да, [команды](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) нужно писать. С помощью приведенной выше обертки для этого нужно использовать метод:

```
execute(String cmd, FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler ffmpegExecuteResponseHandler)
```

Для ffmpeg есть куча различных фильтров, но проще будет использовать специализированные библиотеки для создания эффектов на видео, например, [вот эту](https://github.com/krazykira/VidEffects).

Не очень в тему, но все же добавлю: есть еще такая штука, как [grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika), возможно, она Вам пригодится.

Comment: То есть получиться да использовать `CameraKit вместе с `FFMpeg Android`. Типа записываю с помощью CameraKit а обработка в `FFMpeg`?

Comment: @DevOma, Да, получится.

Comment: благодарю за отклик!